# Trigger default value of a column during UPDATE

Tags: oracle, sql-update, oracle12c

I am wondering about this case with Oracle 12c;

1. Table X has column A, with default value `'default'` and `NOT NULL` modifier
2. I insert a new row into Table X, and column A has value `'not-default'`
3. I wish to update column A of the above row to the default value of the given column, namely `'default'`

Is there a short way of doing this without knowing the default value? Can I do something like;

```
UPDATE X SET A = DEFAULT_VAL(A) WHERE ...
```

Trying to update to null obviously triggers a `ORA-01407: cannot update ("schema"."X"."A") to NULL`, I'd like to know if there is such a feature on Oracle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can you default keyword in update and insert statement. 
eg

```
 update x set A = default where ...
```

This will be helpful for your case and also in another case like i don't want add column clause in insert statement like

```
insert into table values (val1, val2, default);
```

If we couldn't use default then we have to add column clause, same query will be like below

```
insert into table (col1, col2, col3) values (val1, val2, default);
```