# Update column to default value without specifying it in Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jdbc, spring-data-jpa

I wish to set default value for a given column defined in DB, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51317161/trigger-default-value-of-a-column-during-update), without specifying it from my application. What I wish for Oracle JDBC to generate is the following;

```
UPDATE TABLE_X SET COLUMN_A = default WHERE ...
```

or maybe

```
UPDATE TABLE_X SET COLUMN_A = systimestamp WHERE ...
```

since `COLUMN_A TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT systimestamp NOT NULL`

When I specify the default value for the column, JDBC generated the string value in an unwanted format, and I was unable to customize this behaviour, which was explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51315931/timestamp-with-timezone-format-issue-with-hibernate).

Is there a way to trigger this behaviour through Hibernate/JPA? I am trying to circumvent defining a default value within my application, but utilizing `default` keyword within SQL so that predefined value from Oracle side will be used.

I do not want any solution from DB side, but only for application side.

Answer (score -1):

There is a special view in Oracle called `user_tab_cols` which has info about default value for column.

Pure SQL + PL/SQL solution for Oracle:

Function needed for returning data_default (PL/SQL is needed only for conversion from `LONG` to `VARCHAR2`):

```
create or replace FUNCTION get_column_data_default(
  p_table_name VARCHAR2, p_column_name VARCHAR2
) RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
  v_data_default_long LONG;
  v_data_default_vc VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  SELECT data_default 
  INTO v_data_default_long 
  FROM user_tab_cols
  WHERE table_name = p_table_name
    AND column_name = p_column_name
  ;
  v_data_default_vc := SUBSTR(v_data_default_long, 1, 4000);
  RETURN v_data_default_vc;
 END get_column_data_default;
 /
```

Then you can just write:

```
update TABLE_X 
  set COLUMN_A = get_column_data_default('TABLE_X ', 'COLUMN_A')
  where ...
;
```

Comment: I am asking for a JPA/Hibernate based solution from application layer, not a PL/SQL solution. Also it is enough to just say `set COLUMN_A = default` as explained in my question, and other linked question that this is sufficient.

Comment: I don't know anything about JPA/Hibernate, but what about writing a model for ``user_tab_cols`` and use it to get default value for column? Of course it still will be a solution relaying on Oracle DB beacuse of the ``user_tab_cols`` view ...

Answer (score -1):

If you want to update particular column then you can achieve with trigger otherwise you should depend on the Stored Procedure, dynamic sql etc.
for particular column update
execute update script with some inapplicable value from your application (say column_a cant be -ve)
your update statement should be like below

```
UPDATE TABLE_X SET COLUMN_A = -999 WHERE ...
```

create before update on column_a trigger for that table_x

eg. code here

```
create table df (x number default 10, y date, z varchar2(4));

create or replace trigger df_trigger
before update of x on df
for each row
Declare
    v_data_default_x number;
begin
    SELECT data_default
    INTO v_data_default_x
    FROM user_tab_cols
    WHERE table_name = 'DF'
        AND column_name = 'X';
    if :new.x = -999 then
                :new.x := v_data_default_x;
    End If;
End;

insert into df values (100, sysdate, 'test');
update df set x = -999 where z = 'test';
SQL> select * from df;

         X Y         Z
---------- --------- ----
        10 19-JUL-18 test
```

Comment: Adding a trigger is out of question, my question clearly states a solution is required within JPA/Hibernate, not from db side.